# Why does Python's set difference method take time with an empty set?

Tags: python, performance, set, operators

Here is what I mean:

```
> python -m timeit "set().difference(xrange(0,10))"   
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.624 usec per loop

> python -m timeit "set().difference(xrange(0,10**4))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 usec per loop
```

Apparently python iterates through the whole argument, even if the result is known to be the empty set beforehand. Is there any good reason for this? The code was run in python 2.7.6.

(Even for nonempty sets, if you find that you've removed all of the first set's elements midway through the iteration, it makes sense to stop right away.)

Comment: it's even slower in python 3 :)

Comment: I suppose that the makers of python did not think of that because that's not supposed to happen too often in real life. Workaround: check set size before running the difference. But nice!

Comment: Same goes for the most recent PyPy as well, by the way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Even for nonempty sets, if you find that you've removed all of the first set's elements midway through the iteration, it makes sense to stop right away

Comment: I'm not sure this is a *good* reason, but the arguments to `set.difference` are arbitrary iterables, not just sets. The act of iterating over some may have side effects, and it may be more important to have the functions guarantee the same behavior for *all* cases rather than leaving the arguments "unconsumed" in just one case.

Comment: @chepner makes sense -- some operations have specialised implementations, but not all. Perhaps it's just one of those.

Comment: @chepner comment is particularly important if you're thinking in terms of generators - consuming less or an unpredictable amount of items from a generator, for example.

Comment: Why would they bother special-casing this? Sure, it'd save time for set differences with the left side empty, but is that actually a common enough case with a big enough payoff to warrant the extra check when the left side isn't empty?

Comment: @user2357112: It's not just for this special case. For example, {1,2,3}.difference(range(0,10**4)) could stop after the fourth element of the range and return the empty set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any good reason for this?

Having a special path for the empty set had not come up before.

> Even for nonempty sets, if you find that you've removed all of the first set's elements midway through the iteration, it makes sense to stop right away.

This is a reasonable optimization request.  I've made a [patch](http://bugs.python.org/file44565/set_diff_early_out.diff) and will apply it shortly.  Here are the new timings with the patch applied:

```
 $ py -m timeit -s "r = range(10 ** 4); s = set()" "s.difference(r)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.104 usec per loop
 $ py -m timeit -s "r = set(range(10 ** 4)); s = set()" "s.difference(r)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.105 usec per loop
 $ py -m timeit -s "r = range(10 ** 4); s = set()" "s.difference_update(r)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0659 usec per loop
 $ py -m timeit -s "r = set(range(10 ** 4)); s = set()" "s.difference_update(r)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0684 usec per loop
```

Comment: Nice! So, the empty set case is covered with the patch. What about the other one? For example, `s = set([1])`, `r = set(range(10**4))` .

Comment: I did a simple test with `r` and `s` as in my last comment and apparently it does work very fast when both are sets, even if the first one is not empty.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger will the new implementation guarantee that iterators are allways full consumed, or will that be left as undefined ?

Answer (score 4):

IMO it's a matter of specialisation, consider:

```
In [18]: r = range(10 ** 4)

In [19]: s = set(range(10 ** 4))

In [20]: %time set().difference(r)
CPU times: user 387 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 387 µs
Wall time: 394 µs
Out[20]: set()

In [21]: %time set().difference(s)
CPU times: user 10 µs, sys: 8 µs, total: 18 µs
Wall time: 16.2 µs
Out[21]: set()
```

Apparently difference has specialised implementation for `set - set`.

Note that difference *operator* requires right hand argument to be a set, while difference allows any iterable.

Per @wim implementation is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1553-L1555

Comment: special-cased [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1553-L1555)

Answer (score 3):

When Python core developers add new features, the first priority is correct code with thorough test coverage.  That is hard enough in itself.  Speedups often come later as someone has the idea and inclination.  I opened a tracker issue [28071](https://bugs.python.org/issue28071) summarizing the proposal and counter-reasons discussed here.  I will try to summarize its disposition here.

UPDATE: An early-out for sets that start empty has been added for 3.6.0b1, due in about a day.